# Remapping ; and , in vim

Tags: vim

I'm trying to remap ; and , (the repeat f/t commands) in vim but neither seem to work, and I can't figure out why. I've got

```
noremap n ;
noremap N ,
```

in my .vimrc, so I'm not sure why it doesn't work. I thought it might be related to the fact I'm using `,` as my `<leader>`, but it doesn't work for `;` either.

EDIT: mapping was backwards in the post, though not in my vimrc. I'm trying to use n/N as the repeat f/t commands if it wasn't clear.

Comment: Don't do it man, `;` and `,` are such good commands.

Comment: What does `:verbose map ;` say?

Comment: Ah, I'm using fanfingtastic, so I had to have `map n <Plug>fanfingtastic_;`

Answer (score 0):

Another plugin has grabbed those keys with mappings; you can find the plugin with

```
:verbose map ;
:verbose map ,
```

To fix this, change the plugin's default mappings to some other key(s).